# Package path ./standalone is not exported from package

Tags: javascript, next.js, firebase-admin

I'm trying to use the firebase admin SDK, heres my code:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

var firebaseAdminAccount = require("../serviceAccount.json");

var app : admin.app.App = null;

if(!admin.apps.length)
{
  app = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseAdminAccount)
  })
}

if(app === null)
{
  app = admin.apps[0];
}

export default app;
```

the idea behind this is that whenever used, it will check if the firebase admin SDK is initialized or not, if it's not, then it will initialize it, then export it.

My problem however is when I try to run this, it gives me the following error:

> error -
> ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-namespace.js:106:0
> Module not found: Package path ./standalone is not exported from
> package D:\NewRepos\1d3a\node_modules@firebase\database-compat (see
> exports field in
> D:\NewRepos\1d3a\node_modules@firebase\database-compat\package.json)
>
> Import trace for requested module:
> ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
> ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js ./lib/firebaseAdminSdk.ts
> ./middleware.ts
>
> [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found\](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found%5C)

I just installed everything so it should be on the latest version, anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe the `firebase-admin` code is rendering on client-side.  I too faced this recently.

Comment: That would not be possible, this is only on the API middleware.

Comment: Any other solution to this? I had initialized the admin sdk and was working correctly then all of a sudden this error started coming up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like I didn't realize that Next.js middleware runs on V8, and therefor, firebase-admin cannot run on it. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I recently came across Remix : https://remix.run/ for React SSR and was able to integrate Firebase Admin SDK without any issues.  Hope this helps!!